# How to fix black screen after update to 13.04 in a HP 530?

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, hp

After updating to Ubuntu 13.04 (from 12.04) I've got a blackscreen at boot. The machine is running fine as I hear the startup sound to enter my password, I just don't see anything.

I started using GRUB mode and nomodeset, everything is working then but the machine is extremely slow (not usable).

Sounds like there is a problem with the integrated intel graphics driver in Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit).

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: sure you have only intel graphics? post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: lspci | grep VGA gives as result "intel corporation mobile 945 gse express integrated graphics controller (rev 03)"

Comment: PERMANENT FIX: 1. Update kernel to 3.9.3; http://www.ubuntukiller.com/2013/05/how-to-updateupgradeinstall-linux.html#.UaAGZ-cW0jN         2. Update BCM4312 driver following this guide: http://www.mindwerks.net/2012/06/wireless-bcm4312-with-the-3-4-and-3-5-kernel/

Comment: if you own a hp530 don't update to 3.9.3 or you will find this bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/300000/fix-shutdown-on-hp-530-kernel-3-9-2-ubuntu-13-04; I updated to 3.9.6 and is fine now

Comment: Updating the kernal to 3.9.6 (and then applying the BCM4312 drivers patch described above) fixed all my problems! 

Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Try to update kernel 3.9. Boot on recovery mode, open the terminal and use this commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47950494/upubuntu.com/kernel-3.9 -O kernel-3.9
chmod +x kernel-3.9
sudo sh kernel-3.9
sudo reboot
```

*PS: I have a hp 530 too and it works ;)*

Comment: I've updated the kernel to 3.9 but then my WiFi is gone. So the hard choice is:
- Kernel 3.8: not able to use the computer (black screen)
- Kernel 3.9: not able to use internet (no wifi)

Is there a solution to make both the screen and wifi work?

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer:

> After researching quite some time I found the solution.
>
> 1. Update to kernel 3.9.3; http://www.ubuntukiller.com/2013/05/how-to-updateupgradeinstall-linux.html#.UaAIIOcW0jN
> 2. Patch the BCM4312 drivers afterwards (be sure to download the file before the kernel upgrade as your internet is gone after the upgrade); http://www.mindwerks.net/2012/06/wireless-bcm4312-with-the-3-4-and-3-5-kernel/