# Fix shutdown on HP 530 (kernel 3.9.2 / ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: kernel, shutdown, hp, patch, standby

I needed to upgrade to kernel 3.9.3 to get Ubuntu fully working on my HP 530; [How to fix black screen after update to 13.04 in a HP 530?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291023/black-screen-after-update-to-13-04-hp-530-solution-available)

However, the laptop doesn't shutdown anymore or hangs when it is going in standby. I did some research and I found this kernel patch which wil solve the problem: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58401#c6

However, I don't know how to apply the patch? Just copy-paste the text in the terminal gives errors. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I also own a HP530 and I had the exact same problem with the video, so after installed 3.9.3 that was solved but I'm not able to shutdown my notebook properly..! Some advice how to fix this (by any means) will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it updating the kernel to 3.9.6 following this instructions

```
cd /tmp

wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47950494/upubuntu/kernel-3.9.6 -O kernel-3.9.6

chmod +x kernel-3.9.6

sudo sh kernel-3.9.6

sudo reboot
```

source: http://latestlinuxupdates.com/linux-kernel-3-9-6/

Comment: Please include the details how to do it yourself rather than using a script from an untrusted source (can change any time into something harmful!).